# File-downloading gives 404-not found error

Tags: asp.net, download

In the following code, i want the download button actually download the file, but i get the following error:

HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

I checked the path, the file is there. What can be causing this?

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div>
            <div class="balClear">
                <asp:Label ID="downloadLabel" CssClass="balDownloadLabel" runat="server"/>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="downloadButton" CssClass="balDownloadButton" ImageUrl="delete.png" OnClick="downloadButton_Click" runat="server" Width="25" Height="25" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="downloadButton" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>

</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

cs code:

```
string groupURL = "~/Uploads/Group/";
string privateURL = "~/Uploads/Private/";

string folderURL
{
    get { return IsGroup == true ? groupURL : privateURL; }
}

public bool IsGroup
{
    get { return ViewState["balUploader_IsGroup"] == null ? false : (bool)ViewState["balUploader_IsGroup"]; }
    set { ViewState["balUploader_IsGroup"] = value; }
}

protected void downloadButton_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect(folderURL + "abcd.txt");
}
```

Comment: Works for me. Make sure that you have the file `abcd.txt` in `yourprojectpath/uploads/Private/` and `yourprojectpath/uploads/Group/`

Comment: yes, it's there ... i copy-pasted the path that it gives me in the error and it takes me to the file